# How to print Map in dart?

Tags: dart

I know how to print map using foreach() method

```
var x = {1:'One',2:'Two',3:'Three',4:'Four',5:'Five'};
x.foreach((i,j){
print(i);
print(j);
});
```

and using normal for loop

other methods to print map ?

Comment: Which "normal for loop"? Are you doing `for (var e in map.entries) 
 print("${e.key}\n${e.value}");` or `for (var k in map.keys) print("$k\n${map[k]}");`. Either works.

Comment: I mean about "normal for" is `for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i ) ` . anyway the code you sent worked as i want thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also directly print the map:

```dart
void main() {
  var x = {1:'One',2:'Two',3:'Three',4:'Four',5:'Five'};
  print(x);
}
```

The result will be pretty neat:

```
{1: One, 2: Two, 3: Three, 4: Four, 5: Five}
```

You will find the implementation of `mapToString` [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/collection/maps.dart).

```dart
static String mapToString(Map<Object?, Object?> m) {
  // Reuses the list in IterableBase for detecting toString cycles.
  if (_isToStringVisiting(m)) {
    return '{...}';
  }
  var result = StringBuffer();
  try {
    _toStringVisiting.add(m);
    result.write('{');
    bool first = true;
    m.forEach((Object? k, Object? v) {
      if (!first) {
        result.write(', ');
      }
      first = false;
      result.write(k);
      result.write(': ');
      result.write(v);
    });
    result.write('}');
  } finally {
    assert(identical(_toStringVisiting.last, m));
    _toStringVisiting.removeLast();
  }

  return result.toString();
}
```